# Parsedown Escape Broken

Tags: php, parsedown

**setMarkUpEscaped** is not working.

Example of code

```
$parsedown = new Parsedown(); $parsedown->setMarkupEscaped(true)->text($PostMBody);
```

PostMBody is just a textarea, formatted like so:

```
$PostMBody = $db->real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST["PostBody"]))); // Body of the post
```

The page just goes blank and responds with a 500 error.

I'm including Parsedown like so (latest version)

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/_INCLUDES/MarkdownParser/markdown.php"; // Parser for markdown to DB (the latest Parsedown.php file) - the same error happens when I try the break line function.
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Is error reporting turned on? You have given too little code/information to answer this question.

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can simply _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_. You _cannot_ program php without monitoring that log file.

Comment: And about all that stripping, slashing and escaping: more is not better. Know what you want to do, then do it. Do not try around. Programming is no _guessing game_.